# 'Ball' object has no attribute 'body'

Tags: python

I've seen similar question but I didn't get any answers from those. My error is

> 'Ball' object has no attribute 'body'.

```py
class Ball():
    def _init_(self):
        self.body = pymunk.Body()
        self.body.position = middlex, middley
        self.body.velocity = 400, -300
        self.shape = pymunk.Circle(self.body, 8)
        self.shape.density = 1
        self.shape.elasticity = 1
        space.add(self.body, self.shape)
        self.shape.collision_type = 1
    def draw(self):
        x, y = self.body.position # <--- error
        pygame.draw.circle(display, (255, 255, 255), (int(x), int(y)), 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your "init" is just a method named `_init_`, you need two underscrolls for it to declare the constructor: `__init__`.

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.